# I want to make the animation from keyframe start with button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone submit some tip how to do it? So instead of page load , it will make the animation after button click.
Therefore there is negative that every td has it's own class with own keyframe that styles it in certain time.

```
            @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
            @-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
            @keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

            .fade-in {
              opacity:0;  
              -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  
              -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
              animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

              -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  
              -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
              animation-fill-mode:forwards;

              -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
              -moz-animation-duration:1s;
              animation-duration:1s;
            }

            .fade-in.one {
              -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
              -moz-animation-delay: 0.7s;
              animation-delay: 1s; /* Start mezi jednotlivými elementy */
            }

            .fade-in.two {
              -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
              -moz-animation-delay:0.7s;
              animation-delay: 2s; /* Start mezi jednotlivými elementy */
            }

            .fade-in.three {
              -webkit-animation-delay: 2.7s;
              -moz-animation-delay: 2.7s;
              animation-delay: 3s; /* Start mezi jednotlivými elementy */

            </style>

            <table width="100%" class="container">
              <td width="33%" class="fade-in one">
                <img width="100%" src="sekerko.png">
              </td>

              <td width="33%" class="fade-in two">
                <img width="100%" src="miko.png">
              </td>

              <td width="33%" class="fade-in three">
                <img width="100%" src="lakyrka.png">
              </td>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS `animation-play-state` Property. This property specifies whether the animation is running or paused.

**CSS Syntax:**

> animation-play-state: paused | running | initial | inherit;

In JavaScript, this can be queried to determine whether or not the animation is currently running. In addition, you can use JavaScript to set its value to pause or resume playback of an animation.
Resuming a paused animation will start the animation from where it left off at the time it was paused, rather than starting over from the beginning of the animation sequence.

[More information from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state)

**Example:**

```js
function run() {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName( 'fade-in' );

    list[0].style.animationPlayState = 'running';
    list[1].style.animationPlayState = 'running';
    list[2].style.animationPlayState = 'running'
}
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

.fade-in {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
    -moz-animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
    animation: fadeIn ease-in 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;

    /* Pause animation */
    animation-play-state: paused
}

.fade-in.one {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    animation-delay: 1s /* Start mezi jednotlivými elementy */
}

.fade-in.two {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -moz-animation-delay:0.7s;
    animation-delay: 2s /* Start mezi jednotlivými elementy */
}

.fade-in.three {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2.7s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 2.7s;
    animation-delay: 3s /* Start mezi jednotlivými elementy */
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="run()"></input>

<table width="100%" class="container">
    <td width="33%" class="fade-in one">
        <img width="100%" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif">
    </td>
    <td width="33%" class="fade-in two">
        <img width="100%" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif">
    </td>
    <td width="33%" class="fade-in three">
        <img width="100%" src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif">
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much , worked well. =)

Comment: You are welcome.